# Drop Down Drawer Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image]

I am trying to achieve the above layout.

**Approach 1:**

**Main Body** will have two buttons, hereby named BUTTON1 and BUTTON2.
They are inactive initially. The lower part of the main body has few other buttons, drawn in black . When the user clicks one of the button as shown in the 2nd diagram, a drop down layout is created wrapping the lower portion of the layout . This drop down box (in pink) has sub buttons (SUB BUTTON1 & SUB BUTTON2) that will navigate to other pages. BUTTON1 and BUTTON2 will have similar child layout in terms of design.

User can click either of the two buttons in blue and when clicked twice, it goes back to the main body with the black buttons.

**Approach 2:** 
I have another approach where I need to change the design a bit. The BUTTON1 will be active by default. When the user clicks BUTTON2,  a similar child layout (pink) will be created with different buttons. 
User can either click BUTTON2 or use a slidetoleft gesture to go over to the next button in order. Something similar to ViewPagerIndicator. 
Approach 2 seems easier in relative. But then I have to change my design and shift the black buttons to the top of the screen. Not favourable.

I have considered the following libraries:

i )  Slide Expandable ListView

ii)  Pager Sliding Tab Strip

iii) View Pager Indicator

.

But none has been satisfying enough. 
Is there any other library that can achieve these?

Or will the *above* libraries work if I make some modifications of some kind. Please specify any such modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go would be using Fragments. 
they are made for exactly this type of thing. 
You can easily switch fragments in code.

[developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

I hope it helps.